# Display Short Day instead of Long Day PHP

Tags: php, date

The code I am currently using displays the date like Thursday, June 13, 2019.

Current Code: `<?php  echo date("l, F j, Y", strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))); ?>`

How can I display the date like this instead? Thur, June 13, 2019?

Thanks

Comment: There's no `thur` but you can get `thu`. See [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: Thanks @AlexHowansky. I read that but overlooked the D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alex, the correct answer would be `<?php  echo date("D, F j, Y", strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php echo date("D, F j, Y", strtotime(date('d-m-Y')));  ?>
```

OutPut :  Thu, June 13, 2019

More About Php Date Function: [https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp][1]